# Select only some rows from database

Tags: database, ms-access, select, select-query

I have the following query:

```
string Query = String.Format("SELECT ArticleName FROM tblArticles WHERE UserID={0} ORDER BY PostDate DESC", UserID);
```

I want to get not more than 3 different values for the 'ArticleName'.
Is it possible to do that? (without select all the 'ArticleName' just 3 of them?)

Thanks.

Comment: Which database? There are database specific solutions too.

Comment: i'm using '‫Microsoft Access Database‬ (‪.mdb‬)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you can use `LIMIT 3` at the end of the query to achieve this

```
string Query = String.Format(
    "SELECT ArticleName FROM tblArticleas WHERE UserID={0} ORDER BY PostDate DESC LIMIT 3",
    UserID
);
```

Or for Microsoft Access DB apparently you need to use `TOP 3` at the start instead, eg:

```
string Query = String.Format(
    "SELECT TOP 3 ArticleName FROM tblArticleas WHERE UserID={0} ORDER BY PostDate DESC",
    UserID
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to say what RDBMS are you using. Mysql and sqlite support the `LIMIT` directive while other systems may or may not support `TOP`, `FIRST` or other similar directives.

UPDATE: Look at how different RDBMS engines support that. See `getLoadSomeRowsSql()` method in infinispan's [`TableManipulation.java`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.infinispan/infinispan-cachestore-jdbc/5.2.1.Final/org/infinispan/loaders/jdbc/TableManipulation.java?av=f).

Here it is, in case the link stops working:

```
 switch (getDatabaseType()) {
    case ORACLE:
       loadSomeRowsSql = String.format("SELECT %s, %s FROM (SELECT %s, %s FROM %s) WHERE ROWNUM <= ?", dataColumnName, idColumnName, dataColumnName, idColumnName, getTableName());
       break;
    case DB2:
    case DB2_390:
    case DERBY:
       loadSomeRowsSql = String.format("SELECT %s, %s FROM %s FETCH FIRST ? ROWS ONLY", dataColumnName, idColumnName, getTableName());
       break;
    case INFORMIX:
    case INTERBASE:
    case FIREBIRD:
       loadSomeRowsSql = String.format("SELECT FIRST ? %s, %s FROM %s", dataColumnName, idColumnName, getTableName());
       break;
    case SQL_SERVER:
       loadSomeRowsSql = String.format("SELECT TOP (?) %s, %s FROM %s", dataColumnName, idColumnName, getTableName());
       break;
    case ACCESS:
    case HSQL:
    case SYBASE:
       loadSomeRowsSql = String.format("SELECT TOP ? %s, %s FROM %s", dataColumnName, idColumnName, getTableName());
       break;
    default:
       // the MySQL-style LIMIT clause (works for PostgreSQL too)
       loadSomeRowsSql = String.format("SELECT %s, %s FROM %s LIMIT ?", dataColumnName, idColumnName, getTableName());
       break;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3 ArticleName, PostDate FROM tblArticleas WHERE UserID={0} ORDER BY PostDate DESC
```

Comment: I got wrror message that the following string does not work because the DISTINCT and ORDER BY are in conflict.

Comment: Yes sorry. Adding PostDate to the list of columns you are selecting fixes the conflict. Is this acceptable?

Comment: if not, a quick workaround is to write ArticleName, PostDate in a temp table, then to select a column from this temp table

Comment: yes, now it's working, can you expalin what the 'DISTINCT' means pleas?

Comment: The expert's answer here -> http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/12/20/sql-server-distinct-keyword-usage-and-common-discussion/.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
string Query = String.Format("SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3 ArticleName FROM tblArticles WHERE UserID={0} ORDER BY PostDate DESC", UserID);
```